# Meaning of "trapezium" in "trapezium of zoonotic ogres"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is meant by the following quote and especially by 'trapezium'? I can't find any other meaning of trapezium here except the mathematical one and I can't apply that here. Please help.

> India 2025 will be the theatre of pandemics, a **trapezium** of zoonotic ogres caused by the leviathan of callous living.

Source: [Imagining an ageless Hindoostan... ten years from now](http://www.hindustantimes.com/columns/imagining-an-ageless-hindoostan-ten-years-from-now/story-jw4PRPJuqVqRJnv3vCtQzN.html)

Comment: Ha, that's funny, trapezium is just about the only word in that sentence which I do know.

Comment: What a ... *cheerful* ... little quote.

Comment: Maybe "a trapezium of ogres" is one of those fancy collective animal names like "a parliament of owls" or "a wisdom of wombats"?

Comment: On reading the whole piece I am tempted to guess the word the author was thinking of, but accidentally replaced with "trapezium".

Comment: Can you tell us what "zoonotic ogres" means? Is it saying that people in India are ogres infected with diseases that originated from animals?

Comment: @Jos What word do you think was intended?

Comment: @DanBron I can only think of "tapestry", perhaps misspelled and autocorrected, but that makes only slightly more sense than "trapezium".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> **trapezium** (n.)
>   1.1 *North American* A quadrilateral with no sides parallel.
>   1.2 *British* A quadrilateral with one pair of sides parallel.
>   <sub>Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/trapezium)</sub>

There doesn't seem to be a non-mathematical definition for this word. For that reason (and since the definition pertains to geometry), I'm certain *trapezium* is simply describing the physical shape of India. By looking at a map you can see how the shape matches one of the definitions above.

[image]

As you can see, the shape isn't perfect, but if you approximate, it definitely comes out as a trapezium by either the North American or British definition.

Since it describes India itself, the quote is saying zoonotic ogres live within the trapezium-shaped India.